# How can I make "jagged" rows in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is "jagged" the best descriptor here? I'm not sure. I think the following screenshot and mockup explains it well enough. **Basically, how do I get the desired UI with Bootstrap 3?**

#### Markup (truncated for brevity)

```
<div class="row projects">
  <div class="project col-sm-4 text-center">
    Project description and picture goes here.
  </div>

  <div class="project col-sm-4 text-center">
    Project description and picture goes here.
  </div>

  <div class="project col-sm-4 text-center">
    Project description and picture goes here.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row projects">
  <div class="project col-sm-4 text-center">
    Project description and picture goes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Actual

[image]

#### Desired

[image]

Comment: `col`'s are in `row`'s which clear the floats of the previous rows columns. This is what you are seeing. You can't really _float up_. You may want to look into a library like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which gives you the desired "jagged" effect you are after.

Comment: Is there a reason to have multiple rows? Why not one row and multiple project DIVs in each column? `<div class="col-sm-4"><div class="project"></div><div class="project"></div></div>`.  `project` class can have top/bottom margin set as needed. I'm probably missing something?

Comment: @Karl, I haven't done much with HTML layouts before - that is the simplest solution and gave me exactly what I wanted. If you want, feel free to copy and paste your comment as an answer and I'll select it. I played around with the Isotope library and it was far too complicated for this use case. Thanks!

Comment: @Karl Yes you are missing something. If you overload the `row` with more  `project` divs (of varying heights) you will get something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uro5ezk3/). Which is not what the OP wants

Comment: @zgood, that's actually not what he suggested. Refer to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukmpb5gL/) for what his solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason to have multiple rows?

Why not one row and multiple project DIVs in each column? :

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="project">Project description and picture goes here.</div>
  <div class="project">Project description and picture goes here.</div>
</div>.
```

Project class can have top and/or bottom margin set as needed.

Comment: Thanks, Karl! I did find with this solution I needed to add some bottom margin, but it was exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a default functionality of Bootstrap 3. You'll need an external JS library. My personal preference is Isotope - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: I have used Masonry to good effect in the past, too, but Jon has the right idea here: you need something external to Bootstrap. Because of the Masonry.js library, I believe the general technique came to be known as "masonry". Found this article that has some basic CSS as well as talking about the JS library: http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/

Comment: I played with that and it looks really cool - definitely overkill for this solution. Just took some restructuring of the HTML, but thanks for your suggestion!